# How to solve this integral in 3D?

Tags: integration, 3d

I am willing to compute the Fourier transformation of the following function:

$$
\Phi(r) = (I\Delta - \nabla \nabla )[r\operatorname{erf}(\xi r)]
$$

Where, $r = X-X_0$, $\xi$ is a positive constant, $\phi$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix and $I\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix with laplacian operator on the diagonal and $\nabla \nabla$ is a matrix which has $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ in its $i$th row and $j$th column.

To compute the Fourier transformation one needs to compute:

$$
\hat{\Phi}(k,\hat{x_0}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \exp(ik\cdot X)(I\Delta - \nabla \nabla )[r\ \operatorname{erf}(\xi r)]d^3X
$$

where $k$ is a three dimensional phase vector and $i= \sqrt{-1}$. The following step in computing this integral is unclear for me:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \exp(ik\cdot X)(I\Delta - \nabla \nabla )[r\operatorname{erf}(\xi r)]d^3X =
(-I|k|^2+kk^T)\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \exp(ik\cdot X)r\operatorname{erf}(\xi r)d^3X
$$

My guess is that they somehow moved the differential operators from $r\operatorname{erf}(\xi r)$ to $\exp(ik\cdot X)$. But can someone please help me understand how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the differential operator from one factor to the other under the integral sign is just integration by parts. In multiple dimensions, this is also called the Green's identity.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities

Let's write

$$f=\exp(ik\cdot X)$$
and
$$\vec{v}=r\operatorname{erf}(\xi r)$$

You are integrating

$$f(\partial_j\partial_j v_i-\partial_i \partial_j v_j)$$
where I used the summation convention (imagine sums over the repeated index $j$). Index notation is almost necessary, because we are working with combinations of indices and derivatives that are hard to write with $\nabla$.

To extract the second term, write
$$\partial_j(f \partial_i v_j)=(\partial_j f)(\partial_i v_j)+f(\partial_i\partial_j v_j)$$
For the first term:
$$\partial_j(f\partial_j v_i)=(\partial_j f)(\partial_j v_i)+f(\partial_j\partial_j v_i)$$

You can now write your integrand as:
$$f(\partial_j\partial_j v_i-\partial_i \partial_j v_j)=
\partial_j(f\partial_j v_i-f \partial_i v_j)-(\partial_j f)(\partial_j v_i)+(\partial_j f)(\partial_i v_j)
$$

The first term is something we wish to cancel out or send to zero. Last two still need a bit of work:

$$\partial_j(f(\partial_j v_i))=(\partial_j\partial_j f)v_i+(\partial_j f)(\partial_j v_i)$$
$$\partial_j(f(\partial_i v_j))=(\partial_j\partial_i f)v_j+(\partial_i f)(\partial_j v_j)$$

Rearrange and plug into the expression above:
$$f(\partial_j\partial_j v_i-\partial_i \partial_j v_j)=
\partial_j(f\partial_j v_i-f \partial_i v_j)-\partial_j(f(\partial_j v_i))+(\partial_j\partial_j f)v_i +\partial_j(f(\partial_i v_j))-(\partial_j\partial_i f)v_j
=(\partial_j\partial_j f)v_i-(\partial_j\partial_i f)v_j$$

This is exactly what you wanted! Using $f=(\exp{ik\cdot X})$, you get
$$=(-k_j k_j f)v_i-(-k_j k_i f)v_j=-(|k|^2I-\vec{k}\otimes \vec{k})f\vec{v}$$

p.s. did you get this operator from a double curl?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I thought about using Green identities however I don't see why the boundary terms vanish. The boundary problems also exist in your derivations.

Actually, I did not get this operator from a double curl. Nevertheless it is possible to look at it as a double curl, also it might have interesting physical interpretations.

Comment: @user139698 It seems to me that in this case, boundary terms don't just vanish, they cancel out and aren't even there - if I expanded correctly.